# sendTextMessage() raising NullPointerException when invalid phone number given

Tags: java, android, sms

I'm getting a NullPointerException when trying to send text messages to an invalid number (by invalid I mean phone numbers containing alphabetic characters etc., not an out-of-service number)

The code I used is from this tutorial:
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

```
//---sends an SMS message to another device---
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{        
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;                        
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);        
}
```

Having the app crash when the user happens to enter an invalid phone number isn't the best. So my question is what would be a good approach for dealing with this?

I could catch NullPointerExceptions from this code and raise an error toast then, but it seems that NullPointerException is also raised on other errors, e.g. if the message is too long and should be multi-part.

Another hacky way would be to restrict the EditText to accept only digits and the '+' character.

I'm not happy with either of these solutions - it seems to me that ideally the sendTextMessage method should either raise a more informative exception or broadcast an error code for this?

Comment: on which line you are getting the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the input type of the edittext to phone numbers works well. Any combination of digits entered through the "phone number" input widget does not seem to raise the exception (e.g. "#*,()123")

In XML:

```
android:inputType="phone"
```

Thanks to awadm for pointing me in the right direction